# Why good insert throws 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have query generated by SqlCommandBuilder catched by Profiler.

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'  INSERT INTO [BP_PackageData] (pad_ID, pad_Data) 
    VALUES (@p1, @p2)',
N'@p1 uniqueidentifier,@p2 image',
@p1='B265C322-6581-4705-B659-DB9C455C7263',@p2=0x0
```

It works fine on my sql 2008 but on 2005 I get:

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Structure of table is

[image]

Any ideas what settings can make this work fine?

Comment: Any triggers on the table? What happens if you try and just insert `INSERT INTO [BP_PackageData] (pad_ID)` do you still get the error?

Comment: Did you try using a direct insert, without sp_executesql?

Comment: @eKek0 Without sp_executesql it is the same
@Martin You are genius! I didn't thought about triggers. There was one insted of... I hate triggers. I would buy you a beer if I could. Where can I set a question to answered?

Comment: You need an answer to tick. Will just post one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error may be emanating from a trigger rather than directly from the `INSERT` statement itself.